# Getting the stringy stuff off a clementine / tangerine easily?

Tags: food, efficiency

I have a clementine or tangerine (not sure which but does not matter), I hate to eat the stringy stuff that covers the segments so I spend valuable time peeling it off.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Just pith off already!

Answer (score 2):

Rub it in a *clean* dish towel. The abrasiveness of the towel will pull off and hold the stringy parts.

Answer (score 0):

Adhesive tape (like Scotch tape) or a lint roller should do the trick. Just press it against the stringy stuff and peel it off. But that seems unsanitary, whether it is or not. And the adhesive might not stick.

An alternative would be to press a sticky food against the tangerine strings, then peel it/them off. The only sticky food I can think of at the moment is soft caramel. You could flatten a piece of soft caramel, press it against the clementine, peel it at the stringy stuff off, and throw it way. (The caramel flavor might even add something to the flavor of the clementine/tangerine!)